# Wanted to change a number in a cell. Started typing the number but the cursor jumped to another cell on the same line, and no number appeared

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I wanted to update a number on a simple spreadsheet.  Placed cursor on that cell and attempted to input new number (over the old number).  The cursor jumped of its own accord to the furthest cell on the left.  No number appeared there either.

Comment: Is your number lock engaged?

Comment: Let me guess, the number had a 7 in it?